# Download Daymet tileID grid?

Tags: data, download, climate

I'm trying to download tiled Daymet climate data ([see here])[1](https://daymet.ornl.gov/gridded/). One can automate this process using a [shell script](https://daymet.ornl.gov/files/daymet_tile-nc-retrieval.txt), but you need to know the tileIDs that you want.

Is there a way to download the tile grid as a vector file, so I can easily get a list of tileIDs using a spatial selection? Or any other way of selecting tileIDs within geographic bound?

Comment: you can use lat/lng bounding box route as well > https://daymet.ornl.gov/web_services

Comment: Thanks - I had tried that previously but for some reason the downloads were not working, but now I've got it running in a batch file. I'd still be interested in a tile grid, if one exists.